# How to log the error - oAuth2 for Google Apps Script using apps-script-oauth2 library

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0

I am using the library [apps-script-oauth2](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2) to create an oAuth2.0 flow via Google Apps Script.

I am facing an issue in the oAuth flow when trying to exchange tokens for code. The error information I get is:

```
Error: Error retrieving token: invalid_grant (line 605, file "Service")
at Service_.getTokenFromResponse_(Service:605:11)
    at Service_.fetchToken_(Service:580:15)
    at Service_.handleCallback(Service:463:20)
    at authCallback(Code:108:31)
```

Line 108 in my authCallback function is this (see full function below):
 `var isAuthorized = service.handleCallback(request);`

I suspect this could be related to the code_verifier / code_challenge?

In my `getService()` function I am using the library code verifier `.generateCodeVerifier()`. I can see that this generates a `code_challenge` and a `code_challenge_method` for my initial authorization url. That part looks fine.

The request comes back to my authCallback function and the request content looks as expected - but I would really like to see the payload that is sent to exchange tokens for code. This is part of the apps-script-oauth2 library's handleCallback function in the service.js file to see if this part of the code really delivers a nice looking code_verifier and includes it in the code exchange:

```
  if (callbackRequest.parameter.codeVerifier_) {
    payload['code_verifier'] = callbackRequest.parameter.codeVerifier_;
  }
```

Can anyone suggest how to enable the logging of the payload generated through the handleCallback()?

Thanks a lot.

---

My relevant functions are:

```
function getService_() {
  fetchDiscoveryDocument();
  var userProps = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
    
  // Create a new service with the given name. The name will be used when
  // persisting the authorized token, so ensure it is unique within the
  // scope of the property store.
  return OAuth2.createService('mp')

      // Set the endpoint URLs
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl(AUTHORIZATION_URL)
      .setTokenUrl(TOKEN_URL)

      // Set the client ID and secret, from the Google Developers Console.
      .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
      .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)

      // Set the name of the callback function in the script referenced
      // above that should be invoked to complete the OAuth flow.
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
      .setCache(CacheService.getUserCache())
      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
      .generateCodeVerifier()
      // Set the scopes to request (space-separated for Google services).
      .setScope(SCOPES)

      // Set other parameters
      .setParam('response_type', 'code id_token')
      .setParam('response_mode', 'form_post')
      .setParam('state', getStateToken('authCallback')) //generate state value 
      .setParam('nonce', generateRandomString(32)) // generate nonce value
      .setParam('merchant_vat', MERCHANT_VAT)
      .setTokenHeaders({
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
       });
}

function authCallback(request) {
   var service = getService_();
    Logger.log('AuthCallback Request: ' + JSON.stringify(request));
   var isAuthorized = service.handleCallback(request);
  if (isAuthorized) {
    Logger.log('isAuthorized success ' + request);
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success! You can close this tab.');
  } else {
    Logger.log('isAuthorized denied ' + request);
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied. You can close this tab');
  }}
```

Comment: Great. I found a solution to this. The library has a function to modify the token payload before sending. I am using this to add logging and hopefully find out what is wrong. To anybody in the same situation use .setTokenPayloadHandler(myTokenHandler) and define an appropriate myTokenHandler()

Comment: Consider adding the answer below in the answer box. See [ answer]. Comments are temporary and maybe removed without cause.